# Docker: Unable to connect to database

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Been stuck on this for a whole day I can't seem to figure this out. I am new to Docker, and I cannot seem to figure out why I cannot connect to my Mongo database using Docker but I'm able to outside of it. Please guide me.

error

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:832:32)
    at /home/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:345:10
    at /home/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/home/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/home/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1135:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/home/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:344:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/server/server.js:17:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}
```

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: oh ok, sorry I thought it was easier for people to see. noted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 roles:  host and docker.

If your db is installed on host, you should run your docker with the same network config ( `--net=host`) :

```
docker run  --net=host  ...
```

then you can visit the db from your docker container.

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 27017
```

updated:

OK I saw OP put the `mongodb` into the container. If you just want to make a image for demonstration it's quite OK, but in production environment, this is not recommended. because ( personally opinion)  :

1. Every time docker `run` (but not `start`) a image, it create a new container. this is quite normal in Docker world.  and every time the container created, it starts from the origin image, and the DB data is missing.
2. If you don't save your container manually, it may lost data. ( unless you never stop your container)  `docker commit` cost some time in my experience.
3. For new-bees, `docker-compose` seems a bit heavy. specially I think the "port-mappings between containers and host" is not friendly for users. so in this case I prefer `docker run --net=host`.

Comment: OP clearly said `mongodb` in container from the his post...

Comment: This actually works but for some reason my client cannot detect the server and when I go to localhost:5000 which is where the server is listening, it shows that it can't connect to it

Comment: @atline I didn't see OP said this in his post....  are you sure?  @.@

Comment: @SiweiShen申思维 Op did a bad thing to include the detail in picture ... see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZVby.png), he define the database in docker-compose.yaml...

Comment: @Bpun1p I really can't understand. If you run your container with `--net=host` , and still the db connection could not be established, restart your host or your docker.  anyway, run your container with the same network is the most easy way for new-bees.

Comment: @SiweiShen申思维 Anyway, the OP accept your answer, maybe I made wrong understanding ... However, really confuse me...

Comment: @atline OK, my mistake. I don't think the `docker-compose.yml` file is good. I suggest @Bpun1p do not make things complicated at the beginning.  make it simpler. do not use docker-compose if you don't know docker basics.

Comment: @atline it's quite OK~  thanks for your comment and your time~  It's good that OP solved his problem.

Comment: @SiweiShen申思维 Yeah, that's ok ~~~

Answer (score 0):

Change

`const dbURI = 'mongodb://FoodCore:Guy123su@localhost:27017';`

to

`const dbURI = 'mongodb://FoodCore:Guy123su@mongodb:27017';`

Comment: I gave this a try and the same error is still composed